# How to Check whether the date changed in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a script to capture ngrep log daily. But it's not creating file automatically when the date has been changed.

```
#!/bin/bash

month=$( date +%B )
mkdir -p /home/log/$month

NOW=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
LOGFILE1="/home/log/$month/5110_$NOW.txt"
LOGFILE2="/home/log/$month/5150_$NOW.txt"
LOGFILE3="/home/log/$month/5160_$NOW.txt"

while true
do
  ngrep -t -q -d any -W byline port 5110 >> $LOGFILE1 &
  ngrep -t -q -d any -W byline port 5150 >> $LOGFILE2 &
  ngrep -t -q -d any -W byline port 5160 >> $LOGFILE3
  exec bash
  sleep 2
done
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to run your two `date` commands inside of the `while` loop, to update the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to move the variable definitions into the while loop for that to happen.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do    
month=$( date +%B )
mkdir -p /home/log/$month


NOW=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
LOGFILE1="/home/log/$month/5110_$NOW.txt"
LOGFILE2="/home/log/$month/5150_$NOW.txt"
LOGFILE3="/home/log/$month/5160_$NOW.txt"

ngrep -t -q -d any -W byline port 5110 >> $LOGFILE1 &
ngrep -t -q -d any -W byline port 5150 >> $LOGFILE2 &
ngrep -t -q -d any -W byline port 5160 >> $LOGFILE3
exec bash
sleep 2
done
```

Comment: Hi there, Still it's not working as expected. Suppose today is 24th of April, as per the script it should have create 3 files at 25th of April at 00 hour and write those logs to those files. But it's not creating any files at 25th April.
Thank you.

Comment: I won't be able to replicate the script's actual purpose in life (don't want to install ngrep and check fro random ports) the loop creates the directories for me.  What's the purpose of your `exec bash` on the third to last line, btw? I'd expect that to stop the execution of the script.